# No 64bit option for installing linux on VirtualBox

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, kali-linux

I'm trying to install Kali Linux on Virtual Box. It used to work, until I messed up Kali, so I just uninstalled Kali, but kept Virtual Box.

Now I re-download Kali, I'm trying to install it, it doesn't give me a 64bit option.

I have Intel VT-x enabled in my bios, Task manager show's that it's enabled.

[image]

But Virtual box just doesn't want to show a 64bit option for anything.

[image]

I've reinstalled Virtual Box, and disabled Hyper-V.

[image]

I've disabled my antivirus, I even disabled my device guard in the Local Group  Policy.

[image]

I reinstalled Virtual Box. Re-downloaded and installed Virtual Box. I even did an in-place upgrade (which is when you reinstall windows but it keeps all your files and apps).

I've also tried VMware with same results. This seemed to stop working after the latest windows update 1803.

How do I resolve this issue?

PC specs:

- CPU:Intel Core(TM) i3-3220 @3.30GHz 64 bit
- Ram: 8GB
- OS: Windows 10 Pro update 1803 64bit
- Graphics card: Nvidia Geforce GT 630
- Virtual Box Version: 5.2.12-122591

Comment: Do you have Core Isolation enabled?  Be sure you disable it. Update your question, if it is enabled, because it’s very relevant

Comment: There **is** no **need** to **bold** every **other** word **in** your **question**. Please don't do that in future.

Answer (score 1):

I had to completely reinstall windows, then the option showed up.
I don't know why it didn't initially show up. But, after formatting, it works.
Hope this helps others!

Comment: This is not a solution but the worst ever workaround that totally hides what was wrong in first place and does not give a clue on how to fix it.

Comment: I spent hours on this, windows was corrupted. I had to reinstall

Comment: I also spent hours tuning my guitar the first time because my strings were mounted badly. So I finally had to replace and mount my strings correctly. Would you say that the solution for tuning a guitar correctly is to replace the strings ? I'm not contesting the fact that you spent a lot of time and that you finally came back to a desired situation reinstalling your full computer, just the fact that it is not a solution: your action applied the solution without you knowing it, and this is not going to help the original poster.

Comment: I literally ran sfc /scannow, and it came up with errors, so I tried repairing the installation following a lot of Microsoft guides. Nothing solved it. Eventually, I contacted Microsoft support, and they said that I have to format and start clean. Moral of the story, don't talk about something you don't know.

Comment: Welcome to Super User RaidCodes. Thank you for taking the time to close the loop and post an answer. It would have been interesting and useful to know the underlying problem. It is also not clear that you are the original querent as it seems the original account was deleted. It may be helpful to clarify that, and the fact that this was a suggestion from MS support. @Zeitounator, it's worth giving new users the benefit of the doubt, and analogies rarely work the way you expect them :) Above all, bear in mind the [Code of Conduct](https://superuser.com/conduct), previously stated as "Be Nice"!

Comment: @bertieb At least you're friendly 

Comment: I didn't even know I could delete it

Comment: @bertieb thanks for clarifying the situation and for putting me back on the right track. I'm always very concerned when a solution is "just wipe it all and restart from scratch". I didn't understand at all that the OP and the responder were the same person. And taking some time to read over my comments again, I might have been desperately in need of cafeine this morning... sorry raidcodes if this sounds 'unfriendly', it was not the intent.

Comment: @Zeitounator No problem. If I ever face this issue again, I'll be sure to post a solution to it